# Using an extneral function after reffering to a function in Java

Tags: java

I have two classes. One named "`Commands`", and one named "`ZombieWave`". I have a function in `ZombieWave` called "`initiateZombieWave`". *This is the function:*

```
public void functionWait() {
    TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            player.message("test works")
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

This function uses a class called `TimerManager` to schedule a new instance to execute a certain code after 3 seconds (3,000 miliseconds).

When I'm trying to use the `functionWait` function through the `Commands` class, I have to use:

```
new ZombieWave().functionWait();
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to access an external function from another class, is it?
Well, for my question. The `TimerManager`, however, does not work. I'm not really sure why.

[Here's a link for the `TimerManager` class](http://trac.assembla.com/MoopleDEV/browser/src/server/TimerManager.java). The usage of the function is correct, because when I'm trying to use it from the `Commands` class, it works. So why doesn't it work when I'm trying to use it from the `ZombieWave` class? (The `functionWait` is not only `TimerManager`, I just put the `TimerManager` code. The other code doesn't matter).

Comment: `player` is presumably a non-`static` member of `ZombieWave`, thus `new ZombieWave().functionWait();` will cause a different player variable to get used. Vaguely sounds like you need to use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void functionWait() {
       TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               ZombieWave.this.player.message("test works")
           }
       }, 3000);
   }
```

Comment: @m0skit0 This worked. However, in the functionWait, I added a switch for every stage while increasing the stage every "run". It looks like this now: TimerManager.getInstance().register(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() { 
switch(stage) {
                            case 1: ZombieWave.spawnMob(100100, spawnTo, 131, 153); break;
                            case 2: ZombieWave.spawnMob(100100, spawnTo, 131, 153); break;

And so on.. However, the spawnMob doesn't work, it doesn't do anything, and the stage stays at 1 (Even though I increase it in every run). Why is that?..

Comment: @m0skit0 How can I use ANOTHER function from the same class? Using "spawnMob" only or "ZombieWave.spawnMob" doesn't seem to work (They're both static).

Answer (score 0):

You need a new `ZombieWave` object because you're using an instance member in your `functionWait()` (`player`).

If you call this function from a `ZombieWave` instance, you don't need to create a new `ZombieWave` instance. `this.functionWait()` is enough (since `this` is already a `ZombieWave` instance).

If you make this function `static`, you do not longer need a new `ZombieWave` instance, but you cannot use `player` since it's an instance member of `ZombieWave`. You can pass this `player` to the static method though. Here's an example:

```
   public static void functionWait(final Player player) {
       TimerManager.getInstance().schedule(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               player.message("test works")
           }
       }, 3000);
   }

   // Call it
   ZombieWave.functionWait(player);
```

Another way of doing this is to make a singleton class, as hinted by Dukeling, but this means you can only have one `ZombieWave` instance at any given time. if this is not a restriction then you might consider the singleton pattern.

Comment: how can I call another function from functionWait that is i nthe same file of ZombieWave? I tried calling a function from functionWait that is in the same class, but it didn't do anything.